# Adding a GEO2D index to MongoDB via python/pymongo fails repeatedly

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I tried to drop the "guides" table and rebuild it and ensure index for the "geo" field but it still does not work. Here are the information and errors from pymongo. And also why does ensure index always return "geo_1 " ?

```
>>> db.guides.ensure_index('geo', pymongo.GEO2D)
u'geo_1'
>>> db.guides.index_information()
{u'geo_1': {u'unique': u'2d', u'key': [(u'geo', 1)], u'v': 0}, u'_id_': {u'key': [(u'_id', 1)], u'v': 0}}
>>> db.guides.find_one()['geo']
[61.21572299999999, -149.88431399999999]
>>> db.guides.find_one({ 'geo' : { '$near' : [62.215, -139.884] }})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pymongo-1.10-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/collection.py", line 469, in find_one
    for result in self.find(spec_or_id, *args, **kwargs).limit(-1):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pymongo-1.10-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/cursor.py", line 601, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pymongo-1.10-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/cursor.py", line 564, in _refresh
    self.__query_spec(), self.__fields))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pymongo-1.10-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/cursor.py", line 533, in __send_message
    self.__tz_aware)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pymongo-1.10-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/helpers.py", line 100, in _unpack_response
    error_object["$err"])
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: database error: can't find special index: 2d for: { geo: { $near: [ 62.215, -139.884 ] } }

>>> db.guides.drop_index('geo_1')
>>> db.guides.ensure_index('geo', pymongo.GEO2D)
u'geo_1'
>>> db.guides.index_information()
{u'geo_1': {u'unique': u'2d', u'key': [(u'geo', 1)], u'v': 0}, u'_id_': {u'key': [(u'_id', 1)], u'v': 0}}
>>> db.guides.drop_index('geo_1')
>>> db.guides.drop_index('geo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pymongo-1.10-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/collection.py", line 757, in drop_index
    allowable_errors=["ns not found"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pymongo-1.10-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/database.py", line 293, in command
    msg, allowable_errors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pymongo-1.10-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/helpers.py", line 126, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % response["errmsg"])
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('dropIndexes', u'guides'), ('index', 'geo')]) failed: index not found
```

Comment: this is via the python shell right?  Have you tried from the mongo native shell?  I'm not a python person (hence not attempting an answer directly), but this could be a syntax issue with how you are calling it, attempting it via the mongo shell would eliminate that possibility

Comment: yeah, that is python shell, i will try the mongo native shell. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though the GEO index had not been created correctly.

When the db.guides.index_information() command is run, the returned index is 'geo_1', indicating that this is not a geospacial index.

There is an example of how to create a geospacial index with pyMongo here:
http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.0.1/examples/geo.html

In pyMongo, the 2d index should be created like so:

```
>>> db.places.ensure_index([("geo", GEO2D)])
```

Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Marc! As Adam said it is a syntax issue. Resolved now!